# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created one project in MVC 5. I want to call one action method from jquery. This action will return json object. In jQuery ajax id

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

but throwing error in browser. If I set

```
dataType: 'json'
```

throwing

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http:.....

I set attribute in web config and application begin request like

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
}
```

in `web.config` :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

My controller action

```
public class ProductApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProductJson(int Productid, string Key)
    {
        return this.Json(new { Errorcode = "1", data = "data json success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My jQuery request

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://--------------',
        cache: false,
        data: "id:2",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting a content type on a GET request? There is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource" — That text appears at the start of several different error messages. What is the complete error message?

Comment: Content type JsonResult .

Comment: No, it is a GET request, there is no content in the request. The content-type request header describes what you are sending to the server. It is different to the content-type **response** header which the *server* will put in the response to tell you what type of data it is responding with.

Comment: … and you still haven't told us what the complete error message is.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://***.*********.com/ProductApi/GetProductfortestJson?Productid=5053176&Key=12334. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*, *').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it in filter

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Controller should be

```
  [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public JsonResult Getvalue(string Key, int id)
    {
        Result objresult = new Result();
        try
        {
```